# xaml previewer showing only blank page

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have created simple xamarin form application in visual studio 2017.When i opening a xaml file with xaml previewer,the xaml previewer showing only blank page with text "XFPagerendererview" as attached screenshot.Please help

Xaml File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Entry x:Name="user_id" Placeholder="Mail id"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="password" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
        <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065" Clicked="NavigateButton_OnClicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: There might be different reasons for it, since you didn't share your XAML I will try to guess. Do you have a parameterless constructor for this specific page?

Comment: Also make sure you are familiar with the official doc: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Comment: @EvZ iam able to run in my mobile and emulator,but in xaml previewer it showing like this.so no problem with xaml code ,seems to problem with configuration

Comment: You didn't answer my first question and please share you XAML and the code behind.

Comment: @EvZ added the xaml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post the full code it is hard to say what is your exact problem, however I can spot some problems in your XAML:

1. Your page should contain only one root element but you have 2, `Label` and `StackLayout`. So please set use a single view or a layout with child views. As a quick fix put your label inside the `StackLayout` or simply remove it, since it contains the default welcome message.
2. You have an invalid color, that should be #ff77D065 instead of ##ff77D065.

XAML preview might not work that great, there are some alternatives that can be used for example [Xamarin Live Player](https://www.xamarin.com/live).

P.S.: I would highly recommend to enable [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/) so you will get notified about XAML exceptions while building and of course getting familiar with the [XAML official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/).